# How to delete all objects in session except ones names of which are listed in specified vector

Tags: r, memory

I know that I can delete all objects in this session with:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

Now I want to delete all objects in this session except that I have listed in a vector `not_del`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Map your `names` to the pattern argument?

Comment: The the duplicates refer to a single object in the title, the recommended solutions using `setdiff()` will just as easily work with a vector of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
rm(list=(setdiff(ls(),dont_remove)))
```